# Alguém pode me explicar o que esse programa faz?

Tags: java

```
public class Break {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long i = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int count=1 ; count <=1000000 ; count++){
        if((count % 17 == 0) && (count % 19 == 0)){
            System.out.println(count);
   
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Tempo de execução, em milisegundos: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() -i));
 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

o operador % devolve o resto da divisao dos seus argumentos, se o resto da divisao de count por 17 e 19 for zero, entao ele é divisivel pelos dois. Acredito que é esta a funcionalidade do programa

Answer (score 1):

Ele imprime na tela o tempo total de execução em milissegundos necessários para encontrar um número entre 1 e 1000 que seja divisível por 17 e 19 ... Como ambos são primos e fácil notar que o número será 17*19!
Quanto a notação - ${i}  se refere a variavél i  - quando o programa entra no bloco If  especificado , ou seja quando for divisível por 17 e 19!

Answer (score 0):

O programa imprime um número e o tempo utilizado pelo processador para encontrar esse número, entre 1 e 1.000.000, que retorne um inteiro na divisão por 17 e 19 ao mesmo tempo.

É curioso porque ao dividir esse número por 17, ele resulta em 19; ao dividir esse mesmo número por 19, ele resulta em 17.

```js
for(let i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if ((i % 17 == 0) && (i % 19 == 0)) {
    console.log(`${i} é divisível por 17 e 19 ao mesmo tempo`);
    console.log(`${i} / 17 = ${i/17}`);
    console.log(`${i} / 19 = ${i/19}`);
    break;
  }
}
```